# Redirecting Non www to www. using URL Rewrite 2.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I followed these instructions
http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/08/iis-7-redirect-domaincom-to.html

After some tweeking I can get it to work somewhat, but not completely how I would like. Here are my settings:

[image]

These settings work when i goto 'domain.com' by itself, it will redirect to 'www.domain.com'

However, When I goto an inner page on the domain, like 'domain.com/aboutus.html', it does not redirect to 'www.domain.com/aboutus.html', which is how I would like it to work.

I cannot use `(.*)` for a pattern, because there is a wildcard on the domain, which means if i type in anythingiwantto.domain.com it will redirect me to 'www.', which is not how I want it.

What I am looking for is the setting to not only redirect to 'www.domain.com' when it is ONLY 'domain.com' (no subdomains), but also to redirect any inner page in the same fashion.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

anything.domain.com = does nothing

anything.domain.com/anything.html = does nothing

domain.com = redirect to www.domain.com

domain.com/anything.html = redirect to www.domain.com/anything.html

Also, I cannot use conditions to allow those subdomains individually, because there are too many subdomains to allow. I was thinking of adding a separate rule for inner pages, but I don't know how to write the expression for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    <rule name="Add WWW prefix to DOMAIN.COM">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing can be done to remove the prefix also. A blog post for the same at following URL:

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/add-prefix-www-automatically-in-url-in.html